# ROS launch naming detail

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed STDR with info from here: `http://wiki.ros.org/stdr_simulator/Tutorials/Set%20up%20STDR%20Simulator` where I used the "from GitHub" instructions, because it appears that there's no official melodic version yet. I've not gone through that process before but it looks like it worked with out errors.

But when I try:

`$ roslaunch stdr_launchers server_with_map_and_gui_plus_robot.launch`

It doesn't expand with a tab (meaning to me that there's some searchpath problem). Instead I can do this which in the end doesn't work either:

`$ roslaunch stdr_simu<tab>lator/stdr_laun<tab>ers ... etc`

The install ended up installing the stdr stuff in catkin_ws/src which contains this:

`CMakeLists.txt  stdr_simulator  turtlebot3  turtlebot3_msgs  turtlebot3_simulations`

That might be the problem. But I am not sure. Any help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350266/ros-launch-naming-detail/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2020-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` after the `catkin_make`? If not, that's most likely your problem.

> The install ended up installing the stdr stuff in catkin_ws/src which contains this:

I don't believe that's the case. The `git clone` command downloaded the sources into your `src` space. Which is exactly where it should be. I would not call that *installing*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-04-22**:
You're right about the source'ing. But gee I am so aware of that and I could swear I had done it. Wow.

On your second point, indeed the page doesn't say "install" it says "Get STDR from Github". But just to clarify, what would count as "installing"?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-22**:
On most OS, the act of *installing software* would be placing the result of the build phase (ie: binaries, scripts, whatever) into special locations which will be considered by the binary loaders/scripting environment/execution infrastructure when searching for programs.

On Windows this is typically done using an *Install wizard*. On Ubuntu it would be `apt` or some kind of store. On macOS you typically run some wizard which copies files to `/Applications`. Or Docker images could be used, or flatpack, or snap, etc, etc.

But downloading a set of source files for a compiled language into the `src` space of a Catkin workspace would not be something I would call installing it.

I would say a defining characteristic of the act of installation would be that the software is *usable* after the installation is complete. Copying the source code does not make it usable (as you found out as well).